# UNION or Left Join?

Tags: sql

I have try to UNION two tables and left join but the result no I want.Any Idea ?Please Help.

Table a

```
Deduction_No  GROUP_ID    EMP_ID     Service_code    AMT
 PRD533       PRG158      NULL          2351          35    
 PRD533       PRG158      NULL          4854          160        
 PRD533       PRG158      NULL          4857          44          
 PRD533       PRG158      NULL          6611           3
```

Table b

```
Deduction_No  GROUP_ID    EMP_ID       Is_Selected    Deduct_Amt
 PRD533         PRG158     001               Y         82
 PRD533         PRG158     001               N         0
 PRD533         PRG158     002               Y         195
 PRD533         PRG158     002               N         0
 PRD533         PRG158     003               Y         79
 PRD533         PRG158     003               N          0 
 PRD533         PRG158     004               Y         107
 PRD533         PRG158     004               N          0
```

Output,but I don't want to like this (UNION)

```
Deduction_No  GROUP_ID    EMP_ID     Service_code     Deduct_Atm
 PRD533       PRG158      001          -             
 PRD533       PRG158      002          -             
 PRD533       PRG158      003          -            
 PRD533       PRG158      004          -                 
 PRD533       PRG158      -          2351               35
 PRD533       PRG158      -          4854               160      
 PRD533       PRG158      -          4857               44
 PRD533       PRG158      -          6611               3
```

Output using left join

```
Deduction_No  GROUP_ID    EMP_ID     Service_code     Deduct_Atm
 PRD533       PRG158      001          2351             35
 PRD533       PRG158      001          4854             160
 PRD533       PRG158      001          4857             44
 PRD533       PRG158      001          6611             3     
 PRD533       PRG158      002          2351             35
 PRD533       PRG158      002          4854             160
 PRD533       PRG158      002          4857             44
 PRD533       PRG158      002          6611             3
```

Desired output

```
Deduction_No  GROUP_ID    EMP_ID     Service_code    AMT
 PRD533       PRG158      001          2351          35 
 PRD533       PRG158      002          2351          35  
 PRD533       PRG158      003          2351          35    
 PRD533       PRG158      001          4854          160        
 PRD533       PRG158      002          4857          44
 PRD533       PRG158      004          4857          44           
 PRD533       PRG158      003          6611           3    
 PRD533       PRG158      004          6611           3
```

Thank you

Comment: Yes you probably want a left join

Comment: On what condition do you want to join? Why in desired output is ordering in that way?

Comment: @SkinnyJ, I try to use left join but display error result.

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas is order by Service_code

Comment: do left join..It will definetly give output..but I think way u r doing that is wrong..Can you plz write query which u have applied

Comment: Is there any unique values on whose tables can be joined?

Comment: SELECT
    a.DEDUCTION_NO,
    a.GROUP_ID,
    a.SERVICE_CODE,
    b.DEDUCTION_AMT,
    b.EMP_ID,
    FROM Table a
    LEFT JOIN Table b (a.DEDUCTION_NO =b.DEDUCTION_NO
    WHERE b.IS_SELECTED ='Y'

Comment: you expect that Service_code 2351 should come 3 times and 4854 should come only once but how what is your idea of selecting Service_code  ??

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
 SELECT a.DEDUCTION_NO, a.GROUP_ID, b.EMP_ID, a.SERVICE_CODE, a.AMT 
 FROM #a a 
 LEFT JOIN #b b ON a.DEDUCTION_NO = b.DEDUCTION_NO 
 WHERE b.IS_SELECTED ='Y'
 ORDER BY Service_code
```

Will give you following output:

```
DEDUCTION_NO    GROUP_ID    EMP_ID  SERVICE_CODE    AMT
   PRD533        PRG158        1        2351         35
   PRD533        PRG158        2        2351         35
   PRD533        PRG158        3        2351         35
   PRD533        PRG158        4        2351         35
   PRD533        PRG158        1        4854         160
   PRD533        PRG158        2        4854         160
   PRD533        PRG158        3        4854         160
   PRD533        PRG158        4        4854         160
   PRD533        PRG158        1        4857         44
   PRD533        PRG158        2        4857         44
   PRD533        PRG158        3        4857         44
   PRD533        PRG158        4        4857         44
   PRD533        PRG158        1        6611         3
   PRD533        PRG158        2        6611         3
   PRD533        PRG158        3        6611         3
   PRD533        PRG158        4        6611         3
```

Since you don't give me more information I can't help for you, you should provide how data should be selected, on whose conditions and etc.